# Check hotfolder in php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hello I would like to do a track of my files. 
I send 2 files by ftp to a hotfolder.

In my page I check the folder "IN" and the folder OUT.
I use ajax with jquery to see on live the evolution every seconds.

So when my 2 files are in the folder "IN", I write on my page "50%".
The files are deleting by the server during the processing and put after in the folder "OUT".
If the files are in folder "OUT", I write "100%".

So, the flow is :

> 1s = nothing
>   2s = "50%"
>   3s = "50%"
>   4s = nothing
>   5s = nothing
>   6s = nothing
>   7s = nothing
>   8s = nothing
>   9s = nothing
>   10s = "100%"
>   11s = "100%"
>   12s = nothing
>   13s = nothing
>   14s = nothing
>   ...

In my php I do this :

```
 $ftp_path_IN = $_GET["path"]."\/IN\/";
 $ftp_files_IN = ftp_nlist($ftp_connect, $ftp_path_IN);
 $nb = count($ftp_files_IN);
 if ($nb==2) {
 $p = 50;
 }
 $ftp_path_OUT = $_GET["path"]."\/OUT\/";
 $ftp_files_OUT = ftp_nlist($ftp_connect, $ftp_path_OUT);
 $nb = count($ftp_files_OUT);
 if ($nb==2) {
 $p = 100;
 }

 echo $p.'%';
```

But It's a problem that my script in execute every second because when the files is changing there folder, I see nothing, so I write nothing.

How can I remember every second that the files passed in my two folders ?

OK with `session_start(); $_SESSION['p'] = 50 or $_SESSION['p'] = 100; and echo $_SESSION['p'] = 50; thanks a lot !`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you use php, try working with sessions to store information, also you could just stop running the script every second when the file reached 100% 
or
 remove input tag for file not to be submitted again and place a label that fileX was uploaded with success.

hope it helped.